# Есть такой сервис, куда можно выложить код, и где любой желающий сможет его сразу запустить?

Tags: java, github

Хочу протестить свой код. Лично я ошибок не нахожу(почти),  другие люди находят. И вот я подумал - надо отдать на тестирование людям. Т.к., когда людей много, они быстро найдут ошибки в коде, которые я может никогда не нашел бы. Но если я выложу код на гитхаб, то его придется скачивать, компилировать, и т.д(всем это лень делать). Мне нужен сервис, на подобии гитхаба, только чтобы он сам компилировал и запускал исходники. Есть такой?

P.S. Почему на SO нет нативного запуска `java`-кода? `JS` есть, а `Java` нет. Это же не проблема реализовать, есть куча онлайн компиляторов?

**UPD 18.11.18:** Кстати, наткнулся сегодня в [статье](https://habr.com/post/430294/) на сайт, который был мне нужен. [Вот такой](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=aaad7ce772030a46a77f25e2b55f23cc), только для Java и с возможностью запуска и хранения больших объектов

Comment: А чем не подходит вариант самому собрать приложение и выложить его куда-то, чтобы люди скачивали и запускали?

Comment: @Regent Потому что это java. Люди не будут использовать cmd, они хотят нажать кнопочку на сайте и все. Или есть другие способы запустить скомпилированную java программу без cmd одним кликом(я знаю про classpath, но там надо настраивать, и лично у меня не работает)?

Comment: Если "одну кнопку на сайте", то увы. С тем же _"Почему на SO нет нативного запуска Java"_ - не забывайте, что JS выполняется в браузере клиента, а Java код нужно выполнять на сервере: это и куда сложнее реализовать, и даст нагрузку на сервер. Адекватным и при этом самым простым для пользователя вариантом, на мой взгляд, будет скачивание и распаковка архива, в котором будет _.jar_-файл, _.bat_ или _.exe_-файл для запуска и папка с легкой версией JRE (ради тех, кому лень качать JRE с оф. сайта). В этом случае от пользователя требуется только скачивание, наличие архиватора и запуска файла

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Запуск кода прямо на сайте:

- С помощью онлайн-компилятора. Либо уже существующего, либо написанного своего. В существующих придётся столкнуться с их ограничениями, в своём - с трудностью создания. Да и подойдёт это разве что для консольных приложений
- [Java-апплет](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java-%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82) и [Java Web Start](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Web_Start). Насколько я знаю, эти технологии устарели и всё равно требуют установки клиентом JRE, так что варианты из них "так себе"

Запуск кода на компьютере пользователя:

- Достаточно выложить куда-либо (например, на файлообменник) *.jar*-файл, откуда пользователи смогут его скачать и запустить. Да, это требует бОльшего количества телодвижений со стороны пользователя, но:

  - В этом случае нет заморочек с ограничениями на запуск
  - Для упрощения жизни пользователя можно вместе с *.jar*-файлом (например, в виде архива) поставлять исполняемый файл (*.bat*, *.exe* и т.д.) для запуска приложения, а также минимальную версию JRE, чтобы пользователю не приходилось скачивать JRE с оф. сайта. Единственное - так как JRE может ощутимо увеличить размер итогового архива, то можно поставлять две версии приложения: с JRE и без

Comment: Кстати, наткнулся сегодня в [статье](https://habr.com/post/430294/) на сайт, который был мне нужен. [Вот такой](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=aaad7ce772030a46a77f25e2b55f23cc), только для Java и с возможностью запуска и хранения больших объектов